# Power query - List.NonNullCount with dynamic number of columns

Tags: powerquery

in power query I want to add a column counting the empty cells per row.
For this I use

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "Count", each List.NonNullCount({[Column1], [Column2]}))
```

This works fine.

But now I have the problem that due to previous input I can have N Columns (with different names)
The columns names I have available as extra list / table already.

When I try to use the list within `List.NonNullCount` the result is the same for all rows and therfore wrong

How to correctly hand over the column names to `List.NonNullCount({[Column1], [Column2]})` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work:

```
= Table.AddColumn(PreviousStep, "cnt", each List.NonNullCount(Record.ToList(Record.SelectFields(_, YourListOfColumns))))
```

If you need to count values in all columns you may use **Table.ColumnNames(PreviousStep)** instead of **YourListOfColumns**.